# Remove words ending by a specific suffix in a list

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings such as:

```
["l'uso",
 'costante',
 'mascherina',
 'chirurgica',
 'magari',
 'indossata',
 'circostanze',
 'inappropriate',
 'aver',
 'contribuito',
 'saltare',
 'sovraproduzione',
 'anidride',
 'carbonica',
 'ultimamente'
...]
```

I would need to remove from this list words which end by:

```
t_remove=['ito','ato','iti','ate','ata','mente','are']
```

In case of one string and one suffix to remove, I would do:

```
import re
sentence = "word ultimamente monty saltare"
after = re.sub(r'\w+are\s?','', sentence)
after = re.sub(r'\w+mente\s?','', after)

print after
```

My expected output is

```
["l'uso",
 'costante',
 'mascherina',
 'chirurgica',
 'magari',
 'circostanze',
 'aver',
 'sovraproduzione',
 'anidride',
 'carbonica',
...]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `endwith()`

```py
t_remove=['ito','ato','iti','ate','ata','mente','are']
input = ["l'uso",
 'costante',
 'mascherina',
 'chirurgica',
 'magari',
 'indossata',
 'circostanze',
 'inappropriate',
 'aver',
 'contribuito',
 'saltare',
 'sovraproduzione',
 'anidride',
 'carbonica',
 'ultimamente']

pruned = []
for inp in input:
   if True not in [inp.endswith(suffix) for suffix in t_remove]:
       pruned.append(inp)

print(pruned)
```